# How to redirect to custom page when form authentication timed out?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, http-status-code-401, form-authentication

When the website form authentication timed out, can i redirect to a custom page instead of Login.aspx page? I have pretty standard form authentication with following code in web.config.

```
<forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="25" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" defaultUrl="Default.aspx"/>

   <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx">
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="TimedOutErrorPage.aspx" />
   </customErrors>

   <location path="TimedOutErrorPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
 </location>
```

I have tried to have a custom error with 401 statusCode but it's not working as i expected. It always goes back to Login.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

When your session times out, on the server end it is known, but the client end i.e. Browser, Has NO idea as to when exactly the session expired, for any reasons, and therefore will not process anything until the next request is done by doing some activity. At that time it will be discovered  that the session has expired and then attempts happen to login back.

So, The idea is to develop a solution that will track the timeout value on the client end (browser) as well as make the appropriate updates to the server end. Synchronize your server timeout with your client timeout, using Client Side scripts.

You can then present the user with a warning/notification about the session going to expire and force them to interact with it. Read ***[this article](http://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/soup-to-nuts-creating-a-timeout-notifier-in-asp-net-using-ajax-toolkit-or-jquery/)*** in detail that does this.